# How to pass an object from the controller and use it on a view in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to know how to pass an object from my controller to my view
for example, in my controller I declare an instance of a report object:

```
XtraReport report = new XtraReport ()
```

And I want to bind that report instance to a document viewer like

```
@Html.DevExpress().WebDocumentViewer("WebDocumentViewer").Height("1000px").Bind(report).
```

How do I go about this in the controller, I have already achieved this by declaring the report object's instance (report) in my view page and I have no issues but I want to know if its possible to declare the instance in my controller and pass it to the view

Comment: Pass it as a model to the view via the action or `ViewBag`

Comment: please show me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using MVC view model (please don't use `ViewBag` unless you *really* have to):

Controller

```
var report = new XtraReport();
// report is the view model
return View(report);
```

View

```
@model XtraReport; // put this at the top of the view

// Model is the instance of XtraReport from the controller
@Html.DevExpress().WebDocumentViewer("WebDocumentViewer").Height("1000px").Bind(Model).
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `ViewBag` to pass additional (non-model) data from controller to view:

In controller (in action method):

```
var report = new XtraReport();
//...populate report as needed
ViewBag.MyExtraReport = report;
return View(...);
```

In view:

```
@{
    XtraReport report = (XtraReport)ViewBag.MyExtraReport;
}
```

Now you can use `report` variable in your view server code.

```
@Html.DevExpress().WebDocumentViewer("WebDocumentViewer").Height("1000px").Bind(report).
```